# How to get data IWbemClassObject **

Tags: c++, c, wmi

Hello How to get data from this array? Or how to get all the names that I can extract?

```
hres = pSvc->ExecNotificationQueryAsync( _bstr_t("WQL"), _bstr_t("SELECT * " 
            "FROM __InstanceCreationEvent WITHIN 1 WHERE TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_Process'"), 
        WBEM_FLAG_SEND_STATUS,  NULL, pStubSink);
for (int i = 0; i < lObjectCount; i++)
{
    VARIANT varName;
    hres = apObjArray[i]->Get(_bstr_t(L"__CLASS"),
        0, &varName, 0, 0);

    if (FAILED(hres))
    {
        cout << "Failed to get the data from the query"
            << " Error code = 0x"
            << hex << hres << endl;
        return WBEM_E_FAILED;       // Program has failed.
    }

    printf("Name: %ls\n", V_BSTR(&varName));
}
```

Comment: The query in the first line seems to not have anything to do with the rest of the code. Here are several examples on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa394558(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because the results of the [`ExecNotificationQueryAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa392106%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method must be processed using a  [`IWbemObjectSink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa391787%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) object. Try this MSDN sample [`Receiving Event Notifications Through WMI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa390425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Also you can use a tool like the [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://code.google.com/p/wmi-delphi-code-creator/) to generate C++ Code to access the WMI.